# Trouble creating DynamoDB on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to deploy my Python Flask application to Elastic Beanstalk and create a DynamoDB table and SQS Queue in the config file. I've set up my config file (similar to https://github.com/awslabs/eb-py-flask-signup/blob/master/.ebextensions/setup.config) like this:

```
Resources:
  EmailsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        HashKeyElement:
          AttributeName: "email"
          AttributeType: "S"
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  NewBatchQueue:
    Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"

files:
  "/var/app/app.config":
    mode: "000444"
    owner: "apache"
    group: "apache"
    content: |
      AWS_REGION = '`{ "Ref" : "AWS::Region"}`'
      EMAIL_TABLE = '`{ "Ref" : "EmailsTable"}`'

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    "APP_CONFIG": "/var/app/app.config"
```

I've set my default role policy to accept DynamoDB (i.e. by allowing `dynamodb:"*"`), but when I push using `git aws.push` I get the following error on my AWS console: `Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named 'awseb-e-79sqgmxq6p-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [EmailsTable].`

Any thoughts as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, turns out I had an indentation error. The lines

```
ProvisionedThroughput:
  ReadCapacityUnits: 1
  WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

should have been indented one out